# Rearrange data in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZV4uJGmuMHXJfEIbxHd-yYl-qcU3-KpfuMxPgvCXe6k/edit?usp=sharing) with data. In sheet one I have data like sku no, Order Status, date, city, state, Quantity and price.

Now I want to data in this format in my output sheet (please view output sheet for better understanding).

In output sheet I need formula that search in sheet one for sku.. only pick unique sku in sku no cell. Next cell is total Delivered orders in this formula find data from sheet one in cell Order Status and find sku no. If that sku have total 4 orders and 1 return it will describe in output sheet. Please visit output sheet link given above. I fill one raw manually for  understanding. Hope you understand my question... I don't want to enter data manually in my output sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want to pull data from sheet one into the output sheet based on the SKU #. If that's the case, just use the function SUMIF().

```
SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

For example, to pull "Price" into your output sheet you could use:

```
=sumif('Sheet1'!A2:A, A2:A,'Sheet1'!D2:D)
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: some of the part not full .. anyways thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
=SORT(range, sort_columnn, is_ascending)

=SORT('Sheet Name'!A5:Z,2,True)
```

Pulls all rows from 5 to infinite for all columns A through Z in the sheet titled Sheet Name. It will sort the information in order of the B column and it will do it ascending.

You can also Query the information.

Example

```
=QUERY(InputVPData!A8:E30, "select A, B, C where A != ' ' order by E desc")
```

Pulls rows 8 thru 30, Columns A, B, and C from the InputVPData Sheet. But does not pulls any row where A is blank. It will order the data in descending order by the E column.

I am not sure of your exact question or else I would try the correct formula for you. I recommend using QUERY and using multiple where == so you can specify what you are looking for from the first sheet.

Here is a shot at it.

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:G, "select A, B, C, D, E, F, G where (F >= 3 and C =='ordered') order by B")
```

Difficult to read your question, but I hope this helps.